# Do I use a TTEST to test whether treatment 1 and 2 controls blood pressure better? (see below)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, stata

If I want to investigate two treatments (Treatment 1 and 2) to see which is better at lowering blood pressure (BP). The people in the clinical trial have been randomly allocated to be treated with either 1 or 2.

My dataset has:

- BP measurements before study
- BP measurements after treatment
- 50 people in the study

I have done an initial exploratory analysis of
means, standard deviation, histograms to test normality and found my
data is normally distributed.

I've done a ttest in stata by treatment group:

- `ttest baseline_BP == final_BP, if treatment==1`
- `ttest baseline_BP == final_BP, if treatment==2`

Am I using the correct test for this? I'm not really sure how I'm meant to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this answer is 100% correct or equivalent to @rep_ho's. If you have the *same* person measured before and after treatment, you should account for such pairing in the model in order to get better error estimates. I think you could do this by fitting a [linear mixed model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_model) where the person ID is treated as a random factor.

Here's a simulated example in R:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(lmerTest)

set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.table(
    id= as.character(1:50),
    baseline= rnorm(n= 50),
    treatment= rep(c('A', 'B'), each= 50/2)
)
dat[, after := baseline + rnorm(n= 50, mean= rep(c(0, 3), each= 50/2))]
dat <- melt(data= dat, id.vars= c('id', 'treatment'), variable.name= 'time', value.name= 'bp')
```

Show data and plot:

```
dat[order(as.numeric(id), time)]
     id treatment     time          bp
  1:  1         A baseline -1.20706575
  2:  1         A    after -3.01309701
  3:  2         A baseline  0.27742924
  4:  2         A    after -0.30464668
  5:  3         A baseline  1.08444118
  6:  3         A    after -0.02444845
  7:  4         A baseline -2.34569770
  8:  4         A    after -3.36065971
  9:  5         A baseline  0.42912469
 10:  5         A    after  0.26681517
 ...
 91: 46         B baseline -0.96851432
 92: 46         B    after  2.38703598
 93: 47         B baseline -1.10731819
 94: 47         B    after  0.75807376
 95: 48         B baseline -1.25198589
 96: 48         B    after  2.62621774
 97: 49         B baseline -0.52382812
 98: 49         B    after  3.44908863
 99: 50         B baseline -0.49684996
100: 50         B    after  4.62426715
     id treatment     time          bp

ggplot(data= dat, aes(x= time, y= bp, colour= treatment, group= id)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Fit model:

```
fit <- lmer(data= dat, bp ~ treatment*time + (1|id))

summary(fit)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: bp ~ treatment * time + (1 | id)
   Data: dat

REML criterion at convergence: 287.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.13089 -0.62281  0.07085  0.55283  1.85249 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 0.6787   0.8238  
 Residual             0.5464   0.7392  
Number of obs: 100, groups:  id, 50

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           -0.2418     0.2214 73.4559  -1.092    0.278    
treatmentB            -0.4225     0.3131 73.4559  -1.350    0.181    
timeafter              0.2112     0.2091 48.0000   1.010    0.317    
treatmentB:timeafter   2.8566     0.2957 48.0000   9.661 7.74e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) trtmnB timftr
treatmentB  -0.707              
timeafter   -0.472  0.334       
trtmntB:tmf  0.334 -0.472 -0.707
```

this shows that treatment B increases `bp` by 2.8566 units (p = 7.74e-13 for the hypothesis of no difference) relative to A after accounting for the time effect and the fact that the same person is measured before and after.

Comment: it is not an equivalent approach to my answer, I do not know pros and cons of these approaches

Comment: What does lmerTest give you here over lme4? The former I probably should start using!

Comment: @SingleMalt `lmerTest` gives you the p-value for the hypothesis that a fixed component has 0 effect (assuming you are interested in the p-values of course). Alternatively, one could get confidence intervals using `confint` in lme4 without the need for lmerTest.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to test each group separately against the baseline, but you want to compare the two groups statistically. So you can either test if the final BP equals between 2 treatment groups, which does not take the baseline BP into account. Or you can take the baseline BP into account by testing if the difference between final and baseline BP equals between two groups, or you can test if the final BP equals between treatment groups corrected for the baseline BP using ANCOVA or MLR